# Xcode 10.2 how to enable dark mode for Xcode only, not entire macOS?

Tags: xcode10.2, macos-darkmode

I like the Dark Mode for Xcode, but not for all the windows in MacOS - too much change at once.

**Is there a way/hack to enable dark mode for Xcode windows only?** While keeping the rest of MacOS in "Light Mode".

Comment: Duplicate: [Can I turn to Dark Mode only for specific apps in macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/can-i-turn-to-dark-mode-only-for-specific-apps-in-macos-mojave)

Comment: Not working for me, but it should be close to something like `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool no`